# PHP MySQL - Undefined Index in Edit Data

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, undefined

I make file `details.php` that show list of data from MySQL, and I make `edit.php` for it.
When I click `edit.php` it's automatically go to `edit.php?id=detailsid` (it works) but when I click submit on edit data, it's nothing changed and error.

This is my `Edit.php`

```
    <form method="post" action="editdata.php">
<?php 
          include 'config.php';
          $id=$_GET['id'];
          $sqlTampil="select * from data_korban Where kasus_id=$id"; 
          $qryTampil=mysql_query($sqlTampil); 
          $dataTampil=mysql_fetch_array($qryTampil); 
          $data=mysql_fetch_array($qryTampil);
         ?>
```

This is some of my HTML form

```
    <input type="DATE" name="tanggal" size="20" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['tanggal']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="namakorban" size="40" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['namakorban']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="umurkorban" size="5" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['umurkorban']; ?>">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

When I click Submit it's automatically call `editdata.php` but there is no change on my MySQL row ..

This is my editdata.php

```
<?php 
include "config.php";

$id=$_GET['id'];
$tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
$namakorban = $_POST['namakorban'];
$umurkorban = $_POST['umurkorban'];

$update = "UPDATE data_korban SET tanggal='$tanggal', namakorban='$namakorban', umurkorban='$umurkorban' WHERE kasus_id = '$id'";

$hasil = mysql_query($update);

if ($hasil) 
    echo "<center>Update Success<center>"; 
else
    echo "<center><h3><a href=pencarian.php>Back Tampil Data</a></h3></center>"; 
?>
```

There is something in my Error_Log

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  id in /home/lombokdi/public_html/dbanak/editdata.php on line 4 ------ it's $id=$_GET['id'];
```

I have change to `$_POST['id'];` it's still error.

Comment: You are using $_GET array, while the <form> has `method="post"`. Use $_POST. If $_POST gives an error - check, that you have an input with name="id"

Comment: because you didnt pass the id to your editdata.php. neither with `GET` or `POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't have the filed "id" if you switch to editdata.php

add:  `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $_GET['id']; ?>">`
to your form in Edit.php

and replace 
    `$id=$_GET['id'];` with `$id= $_POST['id'];` in editdata.php.

Answer (score 1):

Your form does not seem to include the `id` named field.

And you are trying to read the non existing field from the request.
Request is formed to send data over `post` method but you tried to read `id` parameter using `get` method. As the value for `id` is not found, a `null` is used in `where` clause and that affected no rows updated.

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$tanggal = $_POST['tanggal'];
$namakorban = $_POST['namakorban'];
$umurkorban = $_POST['umurkorban'];
```

> *the value for ID is `$id=$_GET['id'];` ... id come from `detail.php?id=24` (example) go to `edit.php?id=24` .. If I'm wrong, how to set the ID ??*

In `edit.php` add `id` named element to the form with value read from the request. And on submitting the form, `id` goes to `editdata.php` page.

```
<input type="DATE" name="tanggal" size="20" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['tanggal']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id['id']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="namakorban" size="40" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['namakorban']; ?>">
<input type="text" name="umurkorban" size="5" value="<?php echo $dataTampil['umurkorban']; ?>">
```

And in `editdata.php`:
Change:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
```

To:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in php, the value for ID is $id=$_GET['id']; CMIIW and id come from detail.php?id=24 (example) go to edit.php?id=24 .. If I'm wrong, how to set the ID ??

Comment: Thank You very much.. It's work .. I added <input type="text" name="id" size="20" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">

Comment: Change `text` to `hidden` unless you really want to edit it. Or add `readonly` attribute to the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"Update client set nama='$nama',instansi='$instansi',telepon='$telepon',email='$email' where id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
    if($sql)
    {
        $msg="Your Client updated Successfully";
        header('location:manage-client.php');
    }
```

for after body add this query

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from client where id = '".$_GET['id']."'");
                                    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using $_GET to get the id. It is best do `var_dump($_REQUEST);`